# buddypress pass an argument in a button

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I use wordpress with the buddypress plugin.
I am making a plugin in which I have a button.

```
function bpbc_add_custom_buttons() {
    
    global $bp;

    $new_contact_button_args = array(
        'id'                => 'bpbc_new_contact',
        'component'         => 'members',
        'must_be_logged_in' => true,
        'block_self'        => true,
        'link_href'         => esc_url( $bp->loggedin_user->domain . 'contacts/?id=' . $bp->displayed_user->id),
        'link_text'         => __( 'Add new contact' ),
    );

    echo bp_get_button( $new_contact_button_args );

}
add_action( 'bp_member_header_actions', 'bpbc_add_custom_buttons' );
```

This is what this button calls

```
function contacts_screen() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'contacts_screen_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
}

function contacts_screen_content() { }
```

I can't retrieve the argement id that is in my link
'link_href' => esc_url($bp->loggedin_user->domain. 'contacts/?id='. $bp->displayed_user->id)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function contacts_screen_content() { 
  if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
     echo  'id: ' . $_GET['id'];
  }
}
```